# Static factory method OR Creation method

Tags: design-patterns, terminology, definition

I am wondering about correct definition for such construction:

```
class A {
 public static A create() {
    return new A();
 }

 private A() {
 }
}
```

In [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310058) (Item 1) and on [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Other_benefits_and_variants) I found that this is called *Static Factory Method* (some kind of *Factory Method*).

But during reading of [Refactoring to Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213351) (Chapter 6) I met the same construction called *Creation Method*. Also, there is a note that it should not be messed up with a *Factory Method* pattern.

Where truth is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read of this [discussion](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FactoryMethod) of Factory Method.

> [FactoryMethodPattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FactoryMethodPattern) is different from [FactoryMethod](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FactoryMethod) or [CreationMethod](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CreationMethod).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to call parameterless methods *creation methods* and parameterized (for example by an enum) - *factory methods*. In the sence that a factory is more powerful and can create objects of different types.

If you use a parameterless method you have to decide elsewhere which class' method to call. With a parameterized method you pass this logic to the method itself. So the latter (*factory*) also decides by itself which class object to create.

Comment: Sorry, did not get the actual difference between creation methods and factory methods from your post. Could you explain it once more?

Comment: To call a creation method you need to decide which class' method to call - B::Create() or C::Create(). With factory method you just class F::Create( parameter ) where a parameter is some enum value for example and the fcatory decides itself which class object to create.

Answer (score 1):

Creation Method is a static or non-static method that creates an instance of a class.
Factory Method is a method defined and implemented in a class hierarchy and the creation is of a polymorphic nature.

Answer (score 0):

Well, terminology often varies between authors, so I wouldn't worry too much about this.

I suppose, however, that "Refactoring to Patterns" warns against calling this a "factory method", because there is the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Since the factory method pattern is more than just a factory method, they propose a different name to avoid confusion.

I guess you could also call it a "simple static factory", but that's a bit wordy (and non-standard).